# Using ServiceStack Mini Profiler in self-hosted console application

Tags: c#, console-application, servicestack, profiler, self-hosting

Is it possible to use ServiceStack Mini Profiler in self-hosted console application? If it is, where should I put profiler enable/disable code? In ASP.NET hosted ServiceStack it's usually in **Application_BeginRequest** and **Application_EndRequest** methods.

Comment: when running ServiceStack in self-hosting mode, HttpContext.Current is always null. It seems that MiniProfiler relies on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      // enable here

      // your code

      // disable here
    }
  }
}
```

or in the constructor and destructor like this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
  class Program {
    Program() {
      // enable here
    }

    ~Program(){
      // disable here
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
      // your code
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can u put, more detail implementation, try using profiler.start on ctor and profiler.stop on dispose but no result out (js dialog as in web)

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class MyHostBase : AppSelfHostBase
{
    this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add(OnBeginOfRequest);
    this.GlobalResponseFilters.Add(OnEnfOfRequest);
}
```